# ChangeTracker.Entries() CurrentValue equals OriginalValue in EF7

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have a issue in EF7/asp.Net Core application. In my context I create a method Save:

```
    public int Save()
    {
        ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();
        var modifiedEntities = ChangeTracker.Entries()
            .Where(p => p.State == EntityState.Modified || p.State == EntityState.Added || p.State == EntityState.Deleted || p.State == EntityState.Modified || p.State == EntityState.Detached).ToList();
        var now = DateTime.UtcNow;

        foreach (var change in modifiedEntities)
        {
            var entityName = change.Entity.GetType().Name;
            var primaryKeyValue = GetPrimaryKeyValue(change.Entity);
            foreach (var prop in change.Entity.GetType().GetTypeInfo().DeclaredProperties)
            {
                if (!prop.GetGetMethod().IsVirtual)
                {
                    var currentValue = change.Property(prop.Name).CurrentValue;
                    var originalValue = change.Property(prop.Name).OriginalValue;
                    if (originalValue.ToString() != currentValue.ToString())
                    {
                        var changeLoged = new ChangeLog
                        {
                            PropertyName = prop.Name,
                            EntityName = entityName,
                            PrimaryKeyValue = primaryKeyValue,
                            DateChange = now,
                            OldValue = originalValue.ToString(),
                            NewValue = currentValue.ToString(),
                            ChangedBy = "test"
                        };
                        ChangeLog.Add(changeLoged);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return base.SaveChanges();
    }
```

and method GetPrimaryKeyValue:

```
protected virtual int GetPrimaryKeyValue<T>(T entity)
    {
        var test = entity;
        var test2 = test.GetType();
        var keyName = this.Model.FindEntityType(test2).FindPrimaryKey().Properties
            .Select(x => x.Name).Single();
        var result = (int)entity.GetType().GetProperty(keyName).GetValue(entity, null);
        if (result < 0)
            return -1;

        return result;
    }
```

Unfortunatlly the change.Property(prop.Name).CurrentValue always equals OriginalValue, so the if 
`originalValue.ToString() != currentValue.ToString()`

always return false.

Comment: Take a look at [Audit.EntityFramework](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET/tree/master/src/Audit.EntityFramework#auditentityframework) library. It intercepts the `SaveChanges` of your context to generate detailed Audit Logs for EF CRUD operations.

Comment: This being tagged with both entity-framework and entity-framework-core is sort of confusing, as they are divergent frameworks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will not exactly answer your question since I cannot reproduce this issue but this may help you.

In EF Core, the **PropertyEntry** class has now an **IsModified** property which let you know if the value has been modified or not.

You should use it instead:

```
if (change.Property(prop.Name).IsModified)
{
    var changeLoged = new ChangeLog
    {
        PropertyName = prop.Name,
        EntityName = entityName,
        PrimaryKeyValue = primaryKeyValue,
        DateChange = now,
        OldValue = originalValue.ToString(),
        NewValue = currentValue.ToString(),
        ChangedBy = "test"
    };
    ChangeLog.Add(changeLoged);
}
```

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the project [Entity Framework Plus](http://entityframework-plus.net/)

The Library has an Audit Feature (Supporting EF Core) which you may use or get inspired by to create your auditing (The code is Open Source).

Documentation: [EF+ Audit](http://entityframework-plus.net/audit)

Comment: Does it get set to modified if it's different from the original, or if it has been written to?

Answer (score 14):

Replace:

```
var originalValue = change.Property(prop.Name).OriginalValue;
```

to:

```
var originalValue = change.GetDatabaseValues().GetValue<object>(prop.Name);
```

Comment: Thanks, this was what I needed. I wonder now if there will be extra round trips to the database? So I first got the DB values before I start looping over the properties:                
var entsInDB = Entry.GetDatabaseValues();

            foreach (PropertyEntry property in Entry.Properties)
            {

Answer (score 3):

Based on the answers above I refactored my SetChanges method to this, and its working fine now! (EF 6 and .NET 6)

```
private void SetChanges()
    {
        TableName = Entry.Metadata.GetTableName();

        var entsInDB = Entry.GetDatabaseValues();

        foreach (PropertyEntry property in Entry.Properties)
        {
            if (property != null)
            {
                string propertyName = property.Metadata.Name;

                if (property.Metadata.IsPrimaryKey())
                {
                    KeyValues[propertyName] = property.CurrentValue ?? "";
                    continue;
                }

                switch (Entry.State)
                {
                    case EntityState.Added:
                        NewValues[propertyName] = property.CurrentValue ?? "";
                        AuditType = AuditType.Create;
                        break;

                    case EntityState.Deleted:
                        OldValues[propertyName] = property.OriginalValue ?? "";
                        AuditType = AuditType.Delete;
                        break;

                    case EntityState.Modified:
                        if (property.IsModified)
                        {
                            var originalValue = entsInDB?.GetValue<object>(property.Metadata.Name);
                            if (originalValue?.ToString() != property.CurrentValue?.ToString())
                            {
                                ChangedColumns.Add(propertyName);
                                OldValues[propertyName] = originalValue?.ToString() ?? "";
                                NewValues[propertyName] = property.CurrentValue ?? "";
                                AuditType = AuditType.Update;
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Logging it to the database audit table:  [image: Audit logs]

Comment: worked. than you very much