# original and current values the same - change tracking is not working

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

After following this [awesome tutorial](https://exceptionnotfound.net/entity-change-tracking-using-dbcontext-in-entity-framework-6/), my change tracker is not showing that the values have changed.

Here's my method:

```
    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        var modifiedEntities = ChangeTracker.Entries()
            .Where(p => p.State == EntityState.Modified).ToList();
        var now = DateTime.UtcNow;

        foreach (var change in modifiedEntities)
        {
            var entityName = change.Entity.GetType().Name;
            var primaryKey = GetPrimaryKeyValue(change);

            foreach (var prop in change.OriginalValues.PropertyNames)
            {
                var originalValue = change.OriginalValues[prop].ToString();
                var currentValue = change.CurrentValues[prop].ToString();
                if (originalValue != currentValue)
                {
                    ChangeLog log = new ChangeLog()
                    {
                        EntityName = entityName,
                        PrimaryKeyValue = primaryKey.ToString(),
                        PropertyName = prop,
                        OldValue = originalValue,
                        NewValue = currentValue,
                        DateChanged = now
                    };
                    ChangeLogs.Add(log);
                }
            }
        }
        return base.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Why is the `originalValue` is the same as the `currentValue`?

[image]

**When making a change, for some reason the original and current value remain the same. What am I doing wrong?**

The ChangeTracker is showing that 1 record has been changed!

[image]

Comment: The documentation of EFCore states: "Note that whenever real original property values are not available (e.g. entity was not yet persisted to the database) this will default to the current property values of this entity.", see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.changetracking.entityentry.originalvalues?view=efcore-5.0
I know you use EF6 and not EFCore, but the same may apply to EF6.

Comment: That is strange, I have nearly the exact same code implemented for an audit log, which is working fine. Could we see the code where you are modifying the entity please? Thanks

Comment: How are you updating these objects? Are you attaching them or did you load them from the db?

Answer (score 0):

Try use `GetDatabaseValues()` instead of `OriginalValue`

Example:

```cs
entry.GetDatabaseValues().GetValue()<object>(YourPropName);
```

see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52734820)!

Answer (score -1):

The code you have provided for your `SaveChanges()` works just fine. I've verified this in a test project as I've used something similar for a base auditing. This means the problem you're seeing will most likely be something with how you are updating your entity.

For example, updating an entity like this works just fine:

```
public void UpdateWidget(int widgetId, string name)
{
    using(var context = new AppDbContext())
    {
        var widget = context.Widgets.Single(x => x.WidgetId == widgetId);
        widget.Name = name;
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

If the passed in name differs from the Widget's existing name, the tracked entity will be recognized as modified, and your `SaveChanges` override will show the original value equals the old value while the CurrentValues will have the new name value. If the name didn't actually change, it won't even come up as a modifed record.

A common pitfall devs hit is when passing around serialized entities. For example:

```
public void UpdateWidget(Widget widget)
{
    using(var context = new AppDbContext())
    {
        context.Widgets.Attach(widget);
        context.Entry(widget).State = EntityState.Modified;
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

In this case `widget` is a detached entity that has been modified, say by a bound model in MVC and passed back to the Controller to be saved. In this case the entity will be marked as Modified after it's attached, but the change tracker has *not* captured the change because the entity was not being tracked by the saving context, or possibly any context when the modification happened. Both the Current and Original values will be the same updated value.

As a very crude example to see this in action you can use this:

```
Widget widget = null;
using (var context1 = new AppDbContext())
{
    widget = context.Widgets.First();
    widget.Name = "Something New";
}
// Or change here...
// widget.Name = "Something Else New";
using (var context2 = new AppDbContext())
{
    context.Widgets.Attach(widget);
    context.Entry(widget).State = EntityState.Modified;
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

The widget was read and tracked by context1, however that context scope ends. This is like what happens when you load a Widget and serialize it to a view. As far as the view is concerned the entity is just a POCO class. The change tracking is overseen by the Context, not the entity. When context2 attaches the entity and marks it as modified so it can be saved, that will satisfy your first check to find a modified entity, but then all of the columns original and current values will reflect the state of the entity when it was attached.

If the code relies on passing entities around then probably the best solution is to use Automapper to transfer changes from the passed, untracked entity back into a tracked instance for the context.

```
public void UpdateWidget(Widget widget)
{
    var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<Widget, Widget>());
    var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
    using(var context = new AppDbContext())
    {
        var dbWidget = context.Widgets.Single(x => x.WidgetId == widget.WidgetId);
        mapper.Map(widget, dbWidget);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Alternatively you could do this manually by copying over any applicable fields from the source Widget to the DB Widget. Note that it is worth adding `Ignore` conditions using Automapper's `ForMember` configuration to prevent values you don't expect/allow to be changed. Like the first original method that just loaded an entity and updated it's name, the change tracker will only flag and update entities for the fields that actually changed rather than *all* fields, and it will give you the original and updated values as you expect on `SaveChanges`.

Comment: I think it's better to avoid code like this, showing the AM config in some method. I'm afraid a lot of newbies will take this code literally and initialize AM again and again :)

Comment: My Mapper example is to demonstrate the simplest and minimally functional implementation to get the point across. Re-factoring follows to refine the implementation using patterns and best practices to consolidate logic. Mapper configurations would be something set up more centralized to produce the relevant mappers and/or configurations for Dependency Injection to provide either Domain to ViewModel, or ViewModel to Domain projection, Whether the ViewModel is served by an entity or better, a POCO class. Not knowing anything of the patterns the OP is familiar with, this is just a starting point.

Comment: Yes, but surely you see how it can be misleading. You're being too thorough in my view :)

Comment: Not really, worst case left like that it is not condensed, but it addresses the problem of not seeing original/modified values when intercepting the `SaveChanges` in that scenario. Since the OP's post didn't include a specific flaw to point out, even if this does turn out to address their issue it should give them something to look more into, ask questions, and learn from. The example shows how Automapper can solve that scenario. Left that way will violate DRY if the same mappings are declared repeatedly, recognizing and addressing that is an optimization.

Comment: No, it's a huge overhead to initialize AM again and again (depending on the number of maps of course). And clearly people copy paste this kind of code, I see it all the time.

Comment: Perhaps you're thinking of how Automapper started with a Static Singleton where you'd use Mapper.CreateMap<T1,T2>() for effectively all permutations of translations, and now setting up a singular MapperConfiguration the same way for injection. Instead, by declaring scoped mapping configurations, either as needed or for injection there is no "number of maps" to make declaring the mapping config an "overhead". If you need the identical A->B mapping in more than one place it should be consolidated and injected. That doesn't mean consolidating all mappings into one config.

Comment: _All_ configurations must be singletons. Mappers can be scoped, not configurations.

Comment: Not for some time. MapperConfigurations can be instances. They are initialized by constructor. I.e. `var mapperConfig = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => { ... });` `ProjectTo` requires a config instance, not a mapper, and certainly doesn't use any static configuration. Mappers are created from instances using `IMapper mapper = mapperConfig.CreateMap()` or `IMapper mapper = new Mapper(mapperConfig)`. All instance based. The static `Mapper` was deprecated, and removed in v9.

Comment: Oh, and by all means, if you have a better solution to offer the OP for their issue, put forward a solution for consideration and critique, whether it includes AutoMapper or not. Help them find a solution to their issue rather than criticizing and taking someone else's suggestion off-topic.  </thread>

Comment: Ditto, you're obviously trapped in the past. If you have anything worth contributing then put your answer up, assuming you're capable of keeping things considerate & professional.

Answer (score -1):

Nothing worked for me...but this own approach fixed all and working like charm
so before saving did object properties comparison and then used that wherever required in logging,notification and all...
in UpdateAndSaveAsync()
get existing object
now insert new updated one to db
if success, then call DetailedCompare(existing,newUpdated) will give differences
this save this wherever required

```
public static List<Variance> DetailedCompare<T>(T val1, T val2)
        {
        List<Variance> variances = new List<Variance>();
        var lst = val1.GetType().GetProperties();
        foreach (var f in lst)
            {
            Variance v = new Variance();
            v.Prop = f.Name;
            v.valA = f.GetValue(val1);
            v.valB = f.GetValue(val2);
            if (!Equals(v.valA, v.valB))
                variances.Add(v);
            }
        return variances;
        }
  public class Variance
    {
    public string EntityName { get; set; }
    public string Prop { get; set; }
    public object valA { get; set; }
    public object valB { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: This is beyond the point in the question. They clearly state that the change tracker doesn't show changes. Your code only shows an arbitrary way to *handle* changed values. It's irrelevant for the question.